# Parse atq and get at-job id

Tags: bash, at-job

So far i managed to get list of running jobs. I use:

```
at -c $(atq | cut -f 1)|grep "at now"
```

I get:

```
   at now + 1 minute -f /folder/file1.sh
   at now + 30 minute -f /folder/file2.sh
   at now + 3 minute -f /folder/file3.sh >>  /folder/temp.log
   at now -f /folder/file4.sh
```

My typical at-job is call of some bash script files. I need to get job id as well.